# Exposing percentile values of micrometer timer in springboot /metrics

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, micrometer

I currently have a spring boot 2.4.0 project which exposes metrics with /metrics/custom-timer, I created a custom timer but it only gives some values but not the percentiles.

```
    "name": "custom-timer",
    "description": null,
    "base_unit": "seconds",
    "measurements": [
        {
            "statistic": "COUNT",
            "value": 1000.0
        },
        {
            "statistic": "TOTAL_TIME",
            "value": 100000.0
        },
        {
            "statistic": "MAX",
            "value": 100.0
        }
    ],
    "available_tags": []
}
```

I initiated the custom timer as

```
summary =  Timer.builder("custom-timer")
                .publishPercentileHistogram(true)
                .publishPercentiles(0.3, 0.5, 0.95)
                .register(Metrics.globalRegistry);
```

How to get the percentile values in metrics endpoint?

Answer (score 2):

Spring Boot Actuator's `/metrics` endpoint does not support percentiles (it uses `SimpleMeterRegistry` under the hood).
This is mostly because this endpoint is not meant to be used to pull production metrics from it, it is just for informational/debugging purposes.

You can add a "real" registry and you should see the percentiles (e.g.: Prometheus: `/actuator/prometheus`).